# Pending request with file system readFile and xml2js parseString

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is the version of the packages I'm using :

```
node.js  0.10.3
express  3.4.4
jade     0.35.0
xml2js   0.2.8
```

**I'm facing a strange problem, my second ajax request (the one for /tasks) is staying in pending state for some minutes.**

Here my javascript calls :

```
$('#add-task').click(function(){
    $.post('/addTask', function(){
        loadTasks();
    });
});

function loadTasks(){
    $.get('/tasks', function(tasks){
        $('#tasks > tbody').html(tasks);
    });
}
```

And here my routes file :

```
exports.addTask = function(req, res){
    fs.readFile(xmlPath, function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            var ws = fs.createWriteStream(xmlPath),
                xw = new XMLWriter(true, function(string, encoding) { 
                    ws.write(string, encoding);
                });
            xw.startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8').startElement(function() {
                return 'tasks';
            });
            for(var i in result.tasks.task) {
                var task = xmlTaskToObject(result.tasks.task[i]);
                writeTaskToXml(xw, task);
            }
            req.body.index = (result.tasks.task !== undefined) ? result.tasks.task.length : 0;
            writeTaskToXml(xw, req.body);
            xw.endElement();
            ws.end();
            res.send('');
        });
    });
};

exports.tasks = function(req, res){
    var tasks = [];

    fs.readFile(xmlPath, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            console.log("AFTER PARSER");
            // parsing stuff
            /*
            ...
            */
            res.render('tasks', { tasks: tasks });
        });
    });
};
```

"AFTER PARSER" is never displayed in the console and no exceptions are throw...

The only way I found to resolve the problem is to do the second ajax call with a timeout, like this :

```
$.post('/addTask', function(){
    setTimeout(loadTasks, 100);
});
```

Someone can tell me what's wrong ? I guess it's a file access problem or something like that.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you writing anything in addTask? Are you closing the file afterwards? I don't think you are showing all the code that is needed to answer. My answer below points to another problem.

Comment: Ok I edited, how can I close the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending a response. `res.render` does not do a res.send.

This should work:

```
        res.render('tasks', { tasks: tasks }, 
                   function(err, html) { res.send(html); } );
```

**Edit:**
The other part of the problem regards closing the file. You need to wait for the .end() to finish (http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback):

```
        xw.endElement();
        ws.on('finish', function() {
            res.send('');
        });
        ws.end();
```

Comment: Well I tried but the problem is still here, actually I think it doesn't reach this part because "AFTER PARSER" is not show in the console.

Comment: Thanks, it works with that. I knew it was a file access problem but wasn't aware that end() did the job async.

Comment: Isn't *everything* async in node.js? :-)

Comment: Yeah right, I'm new into node.js so it's hard to be always aware of that ahaha.